# Limit of a sequence (square root+binomial coeffitiens)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Could you help me computing this limit?
Thank you!

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\binom{2n+1}{n+1}}\frac{n}{4\sqrt[n]{(n+1)!}}.$$

Comment: I read the solution given by my teacher which was substantially the same of rom. I couldn't understand the last step, which I now reckon to be the IV Cesaro's theorem.

Comment: See [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties) and [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 1):

$lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{(n+1)!}} = lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]\frac{n^n}{(n+1)!} = lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}(n+1)!}{(n+2)!n^n} = lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+2)n^n}=e$

and $lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\binom{2n+1}{n+1}}=4$

by applying $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ = $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.

Comment: Is this enough to keep going or do I need to add details ? :)